# React component failed to render without any error or warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a React component like this. My goal is to render a checklist for shopping, with toggles (lower order component) that would update the state of this higher order component when clicked.
It may look something like this

1.Fruits

Banana                    (Button)

Kiwi Fruit                (Button)

2.Other snacks

Potato chips              (Button)

Instant noodles           (Button)

Sugarfree mint            (Button)

```
let shopping_list = [
    {
        Fruits: [
            { Banana: "banana" },
            { "Kiwi fruit": "kiwi" },
        ]
    },
    {
        'Other snacks': [
            { "Potato chips": "potato_chips" },
            { "Instant noodles ": "instant_noodles" },
            { "Sugarfree mint": "sugar_free_mint" }]
    }
]

class ShoppingList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.btnClicked.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            banana: false,
            kiwi: false,
            potato_chips: false,
            instant_noodles: false,
            sugar_free_mint: false,
        }
    }

    btnClicked = (e) => {
        let obj = {};
        obj[e.currentTarget.id] = !(this.state[e.currentTarget.id]);
        this.setState(obj);
    }

    createToggle = (content, attribute) => {
        return (
            <Row key={attribute}>
                <Col>
                    {content}
                </Col>
                <Col xs="2">
                    <Chips label="&#x2713;"
                        id={attribute} onClick={this.btnClicked} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }

    createNestedToggle = (shopping_list) => {
        //console.log("creating nested toggle")
        //console.log(this)
        shopping_list.map( (section, index) =>
        
        (   <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <Row className="table_text" style={{paddingTop: 5}}>
                <Col xs="12" style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                    {index+1}.{(Object.keys(section))[0]}  
                </Col>
            </Row>

            {   (Object.values(section))[0].map((item) => {
                this.createToggle(
                    (Object.keys(item))[0],
                    (Object.values(item))[0]
                    )
                    }
                )
            }
        </React.Fragment>
            ))
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <Title type="title" content="Shopping list" />
                ...
                {/**Some rows and columns in here */}
                <div>
                    {this.createNestedToggle(shopping_list)}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {/**Some rows and columns in here */}
                </div>
            </div>)
    }
}
```

But the shopping list wasn't rendered properly, it was missing. When I was debugging, I tried adding console log messages to the function createNestedToggle as you can see, and they're actually logged. I am not sure what exactly is wrong with the second block.

Things I've tried

I have tried writing the createToggle part into a functional component to simplify the code - however,
as I need the toggles to call back the HOC I have to make createToggle a part of ShoppingList class.

I am quite new to React JS(JS to be exact), so maybe I am doing the whole thing in a way that's
completely wrong. If you could suggest me a better way to do it, I would be very grateful as well.
Any help or hint would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: `createNestedToggle` does not return anything, so nothing will be rendered.

Comment: Additionally, `this.btnClicked.bind(this)` doesn't update the function in place, it returns a value, so you'd need to assign this to something if you want to use it, e.g. `this.btnClicked = this.btnClicked.bind(this)`. **However** since you are already defining it as a [public class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), you don't need to do this at all.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your prompt replies. From  @TsvetanGanev's answer, it seems like I am using the arrow function wrongly. I modified the arrow function to this: `createNestedToggle = (shopping_list) => { return(……) }`
There’s something showing up, but only the section titles(like this
1.Fruits
2.Other snacks
So I am still not sure what is happening with the other block.
I have tried doing something like 
`{some_list.map( item => this.createToggle(item.content, item.attribute) )}`
And this list was displayed properly. So I think the issue wasn’t with the createToggle function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I have modified the createNestedToggle function as the following and it worked

```
createNestedToggle = (part_iii) => {
        return(
            <div>
                {part_iii.map( (section, index) =>
            
                <div key={index}>
                   ...
                    
                    {   
                        (Object.values(section))[0].map((item) => {
                            return(
                                this.createToggle(
                                    (Object.keys(item))[0],(Object.values(item))[0] )
                            )
                            
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    
                    
                </div>
                )}
            </div>
            
            )
        
    }
```

I was always confused by the arrow function notation and didn't realise that it has to be `()=>{...return ...}` . (Yep I should read the docs more carefully) I will leave this post here in case any future Googlers need it. Thanks for everyone's answer.